# Which Linux is working on ASUS laptop

Tags: linux, nvidia-graphics-card, optimus

I have recently got an ASUS N75S (http://www.asus.com/Notebooks/Multimedia_Entertainment/N75SF/) and since then I'm struggling to install a linux distro on it. None of them work with full graphics resolution (Nvidia GT 555M + Optimus) due to the Optimus Nvidia technology, the nouveau driver crashes on bootup and the bumblebee is simply not working with the nvidia driver coming with the distros I have tried (Fedora, Ubuntu, Mint, Debian), the official Nvidia 290.10 driver is not doing anything useful either...

Do you have any experience in bringing up the graphics on a computer similar with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly there are no out-of-the-box working Nvidia Optimus drivers available at all. I am facing the same problem with my laptop.

It is said that nvidia puts the blame on X11 and the impossibility to develop an optimus driver for it. (X is pretty messy as far as I know - old and a lot of patchwork - there are a lot of people that demand a total revamp).

One possibility is to use the intel driver and not use the nvidia chip at all. Everything else involves a lot of tinkering and I have not yet tried it myself (will do it after I finished all of this semesters tests):

- Check the [gentoo wiki](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/X.Org/nVidia_Optimus) on Optimus for setting up two x-servers, you use one to display with the intel card and the nvidia screen is used to render stuff.
- [Hybrid Graphic Linux](https://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux) might be a page worth a read, too
- There is also a project called [prime-ng](http://osdir.com/ml/hybrid-graphics-linux/2011-05/msg00115.html), but I cannot find a good source of information about it, maybe it allready was renamed (as suggested in that post).

Comment: I have just tested Ubuntu 12.04 alpha 2, it starts with nicely recognizing the HD screen, so there is some hope that when releasing it there will be something working at least.

Comment: prime-ng has been dropped. Use [Bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org/) instead. See also [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](http://askubuntu.com/q/36930/6969)